# ActiveMQ lost messages if there is no commit pending on MDB with XA and RA

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, wildfly, xa, amazon-mq

We recently migrate from Artemis to ActiveMQ and now we are facing some strange behavior with our Message Driven Beans.

Basically, when some application fails, we realize that some messages are lost. We made some tests to identify if there is some configuration issue with ack type, message persistence, etc. But in the end, the conclusion we came, and the test scenario we get, is that when we have a MDB processing the message and there is no transaction with a pending commit, when the application dies, the message is lost, the broker removes it from the pending messages.

But, if we do have a transaction with a pending commit, the broker keeps it, and soon the application starts the message can be processed again.

We are using XA and Resource Adapter with a WildFly Swarm application. Looks like as soon a transaction starts from the MDB and there is a commit pending, the application notifies the broker to hold the message even if the consumer dies. If there is no transaction, as soon the broker identifies that the consumer has lost connection, the messages are removed from the queue.

**Some infos:**

- Even defining with transaction required and container management, the same occurs
- With auto or dups ack, the same occurs
- The messages are persistent

We are missing some configuration with activeMQ? We don't find any other property saying something about this kind of behavior with MDBs and transactions. What tells the broker that he should hold the messages with going transactions? There is a way to keep all the messages in case of failure using MDBs and XA?

Here is a simple MDB code with the test scenario:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "task-processor"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSessions", propertyValue = "20")
})
@ResourceAdapter("activemq-rar.rar")
public class MyMDB implements MessageListener {

@Inject
private CartaoService service;

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    try {
        // 0 - No transaction
        // 1 - Will be a transaction with a pending commit
        int t = new Random().nextInt(2);

       // Just a entity to persist and have a pending commit
        Cartao c = new Cartao();
        c.setIdBoard(1l);
        c.setNome(((TextMessage) message).getText());
        c.setStatus("ON");
        c.setTempo(10l);

        // Prints the message id and if there is a transaction
        System.out.println(((TextMessage) message).getJMSMessageID() + " - " + t);

        // Sometimes we will have a commit pending
        if (t == 1)
           service.insert(c);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
        System.out.println("END");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


}
```

The insert method is just a method that persists the entity and is transaction required.